# sqlite добавление пустых строк между группами

Tags: sqlite

Допустим есть запрос

```
SELECT r.role_name, u.user_name 
FROM user u 
INNER JOIN roles r ON u.role_id = r.id
ORDER BY r.role_name
```

который даёт вывод

```
role_name   user_name
---------   -----------
admin       Ivanov I.I.
admin       Petrov P.P.
user        Sidorov S.S.
user        Ivanov P.S.
```

Можно ли сделать, чтобы при изменении `role_name` добавлялась пустая строка (либо какая-нибудь заданная), чтобы вывод стал таким

```
role_name   user_name
---------   -----------
admin       Ivanov I.I.
admin       Petrov P.P.
                             <-- тут либо пустая строка, либо разделитель
user        Sidorov S.S.
user        Ivanov P.S.
```

Comment: А вы не хотите это уже на клиенте сделать, БД слабо приспособлены для задач красивого оформления вывода ... Хотя конечно с точки зрения SQL задача интересная ...

Comment: На клиенте у меня мысли только сравнивать предыдущее значение поля с текущим, и при изменении добавлять пустую строку, что достаточно трудоемко для клиента, да и не очень красиво. Вот интересно, может можно как на сервере. У `MSSQL` это вроде можно сделать с помощью `rollup` и условия `case when groupping(role_name)=1 then "" else role_name end` (может обманываю с кодом, давно уже не работал с `MSSQL`)

Comment: Вот иденно так и делают, сравнивают предыдущее с следующим. А диалект у sqlite слабоват, rollup тяжело эмулировать. Да еще вдобавок надо после него правильно отсортировать ...

Comment: Отсортировано по полю `role_name` изначально, забыл это указать, поправил вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select case when user_name is null then NULL else role_name end as role_name,
       user_name
  from (
     SELECT r.role_name, u.user_name 
      FROM user u INNER JOIN roles r ON u.role_id = r.id
    union all
     SELECT distinct r.role_name, NULL
      FROM user u INNER JOIN roles r ON u.role_id = r.id
  ) A
  order by A.role_name, case when user_name is null then 1 else 0 end
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает, только не совсем понял сортировку по `user_name`. У себя реализовал как `case when user_name is null then 'яяяяяяяяяяя' else user_name end`, чтобы пустая строка была под группой

Comment: @ЭдуардИзмалков Так в вопросе ничего про сортировку по пользователю не было, поэтому я просто 0 и 1 сделал что бы в конце NULL было